# How to remove heat from a body and cool it below room temperature?

Tags: current, heat, cooling

In college I was told that we can heat a metal sheet if we pass enough current through it (Eddy currents).

But is it possible to somehow cool an object (metal sheet) using some circuit? The temperature of the sheet should be brought down below the room temperature and that too instantly.

I am making a glove that heats up or cools down according to the values it receives from another arduino. The temperature ranges might be between 10 degree celsius to 35 degree celsius.
By instantly I mean around 30 seconds..

Comment: Electric cooling (moving heat to another location) is possible with Peltier devices, but they're not very efficient and certainly not instant.

Comment: So is there any other way? I need to heat or cool a sheet of metal according to the signal that i give to an arduino..

Comment: Either find a source of coolant below room temperature (like a cold water supply) or use a compressor type heat pump, if you can't afford Peltier efficiency.

Comment: Approximately, how much heat do you need to remove from the metal object? What is the temperature of the object? How fast is "instantly"?

Comment: @gbulmer i made the required changes in the question..

Comment: That helps. So this is effectively a heated or cooled glove, and your intention is the 'metal object' is the heating or cooling component?

Comment: exactly. If i don't get any other methods, i might use water cooling..

Answer (score 2):

Anything with a mass will have no instant temperature response. Thermal mass and conductivity limit on how fast you can cool something. Special processes do reach cooling rates of over 1 million Kelvin per second, but that is a huge machine and not a simple circuit (and is basically used with liquid metal to begin with, so not applicable).

[Joule heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating) (nothing to do with eddy currents) works because the energy carried by the current is converted into heat. This effect cannot be reversed. That is if you only have a sheet of metal and a voltage/current source there is no way to do it.

If you are able to attach something different to the metal sheet then you can use a [Peltier element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling), but they are not very efficient and you need a lot of of cooling power for fast cooling rates which transfers to even more power needed for the Peltier elements.

But if you are able to attach something to the sheet, then maybe you can just hook up a normal compression type refrigerator and switch that on and off with a relay.

Comment: You wrote "Joule heating works because the energy carried by the current is converted into heat.  This effect cannot be reversed in a simple way." What is the complex way to reverse Joule heating? AFAIK, this is 'entropy in action', a fundamental feature of the universe, and hence "can not be reversed". However, I am very willing to learn something new.

Comment: @gbulmer yeah, I was thinking about wording it very strongly (as in cannot be reversed). Depending on which way you see "reversing" you could think about it as cooling something and getting out a current, that can be done with a thermoelectric generator, although cooling isn't something which can be done in an easy way as everything tends to have the same temperature. I'll scratch that before this turns into a free energy blob.